# Create and download file is working on one page and fails on another - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the same code to create an Excel file and download it on several pages.

The code is working fine.

```
byte[] report = //get report as bytes

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Filename.xlsx"));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.BinaryWrite(report);
Response.End();
```

I try to add it to another page, but it does not work. It gets stuck on the last line of code:

```
Response.End();
```

It isn't related to the report content, I tried to get the same report data on two pages and it worked on one and failed on the other.

It appears to be something in the page settings, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I added a trigger to the button that executes the code and the issue is resolved.

The code looks like this:

In aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="btnExportToExcel_Click" />
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExportToExcel" />
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void btnBudgetExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     byte[] report = //get report as bytes

     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Filename.xlsx"));
     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
     Response.BinaryWrite(report);
     Response.End();
}
```